# How to synchronize threads of different classes on the same method

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

My doubt concerns the way to synchronize threads of different classes which use the same method. I have two different classes, `ClientA` and `ClientB` (which obviously extend Thread) and a method of a Server class. Both the threads of `ClassA` and `ClassB` have to use this method, but there are different policies about the access:

- If a thread of `ClassA` is using a resource inside the method, other threads of the same class can use it;
- If a thread of `ClassB` is using the method, nobody (both thread of `ClassA` and `ClassB`) can use it (mutual exclusion).

So this is my question: how can I apply this policy of synchronization? I used a semaphore (mutex) at the beginning of the method but I'm not sure about this solution, because I think this will block every type of thread every time.

Comment: A [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) would do the job, but you'll have to time it to figure out whether the overhead is worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you think there are no different ways to use semaphores?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock to achieve that.

Example a little different. ClientA let all enter, ClientB does not:

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private void method(boolean exclusive){
        log.debug("Before lock() ");
            try {
                lock.lock();
                if (!exclusive) {
                    lock.unlock();
                }

                log.debug("Locked part");
                //Method tasks....
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){
                log.error("",e);
            }finally {
                if(exclusive)
                    lock.unlock();
            }
         log.debug("End ");
    }
```

Execution:

```
new Thread("no-exclusive1"){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        method(false);
    }
}.start();
new Thread("exclusive1"){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        method(true);
    }
}.start();
new Thread("exclusive2"){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        method(true);
    }
}.start();
new Thread("no-exclusive2"){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        method(false);
    }
}.start();
```

Result:

```
01:34:32,566 DEBUG (no-exclusive1) Before lock() 
01:34:32,566 DEBUG (no-exclusive1) Locked part
01:34:32,566 DEBUG (exclusive1) Before lock() 
01:34:32,566 DEBUG (exclusive1) Locked part
01:34:32,567 DEBUG (exclusive2) Before lock() 
01:34:32,567 DEBUG (no-exclusive2) Before lock() 
01:34:33,566 DEBUG (no-exclusive1) End 
01:34:33,567 DEBUG (exclusive1) End 
01:34:33,567 DEBUG (exclusive2) Locked part
01:34:34,567 DEBUG (exclusive2) End 
01:34:34,567 DEBUG (no-exclusive2) Locked part
01:34:35,567 DEBUG (no-exclusive2) End
```

Comment: So I should use a sort of boolean "flag" to decide the way to proceed. I already thought about this solution. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little complex, but I nevertheless thought it would be interesting to demonstrate how you might consider doing it with only synchronized blocks:

```
public class Server() {

    private LinkedList<Object> lockQueue = new LinkedList<Object>();

    public void methodWithMultipleAccessPolicies(Object client) {
        Object clientLock = null;

        // These aren't really lock objects so much as they are
        // the targets for synchronize blocks.  Get a different
        // type depending on the type of the client.
        if (client instanceof ClientA) {
            clientLock = new ALock();
        } else {
            clientLock = new BLock();
        }

        // Synchronize on the "lock" created for the current client.
        // This will never block the current client, only those that
        // get to the next synchronized block afterwards.
        synchronized(clientLock) {
            List<Object> locks = null;

            // Add it to the end of the queue of "lock" objects.
            pushLock(clientLock);

            // Instances of ClientA wait for all instances of
            // ClientB already in the queue to finish.  Instances
            // of ClientB wait for all clients ahead of them to
            // finish.
            if (client instanceof ClientA) {
                locks = getBLocks();
            } else {
                locks = getAllLocks();
            }
            // Where the waiting occurs.
            for (Lock lock : locks) {
                synchronized(lock) {}
            }

            // Do the work.  Instances of ClientB should have
            // exclusive access at this point as any other clients
            // added to the lockQueue afterwards will be blocked
            // at the for loop.  Instances of ClientA should
            // have shared access as they would only be blocked
            // by instances of ClientB ahead of them.
            methodThatDoesTheWork();

            // Remove the "lock" from the queue.
            popLock(clientLock);
        }
    }

    public void methodThatDoesTheWork() {
        // Do something.
    }

    private synchronized void pushLock(Object lock) {
        lockQueue.addLast(lock);
    }

    private synchronized void popLock(Object lock) {
        lockQueue.remove(lock);
    }

    private synchronized List<Object> getAllLocks() {
        return new ArrayList<Object>(lockQueue);
    }

    private synchronized List<Object> getBLocks() {
        ArrayList<Object> bLocks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object lock : lockQueue) {
            if (lock instanceof BLock) {
                bLocks.add(lock);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ALock {}
public class BLock {}
```

Comment: This solution looks like more complex than the other one, but surely can be useful. Can I use the `QueuedThreads` list associated to the `ReentrantLock` instead of the `LinkedLIst<Object>`? Thank you for answering!

Comment: You would really just want simple java objects in the list.  The locking comes entirely from the synchronized blocks.  If you're using the ReentrantLocks the way they are meant to, it might conflict with synchronized blocks.

Comment: Oh, and also make sure you test it thoroughly if you use it.  Pretty sure it's a solid solution, but it's also entirely from my head.  :)

Comment: And just to make sure you're aware, there are three levels of synchronization going on. 1) The outer synchronization block. 2) The inner for loop. 3) The synchronized method calls that modify the queue. All three are important.  Also, the order in which everything happes is important too.  Have I scared you off yet?  :)

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your comments are very very useful!